# Is it possible to build a Qt project using external libraries

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, mingw

I made a project using OpenCV library that works perfectly on my computer when I run the .exe but it doesn't when I open it in other computers. I placed all QT and Opencv dlls used in the same folder but still when I run it stays loading for a while and then nothing happens.

Is there a right way to include/embed an external library in the files?

Comment: You mean about deployment ? You are trying to run in a different environment without installing any library and also without deployment?

Comment: Yes exactly, I would like to be able to transfer only files to other environment without needing to install OpenCV

Comment: This is only possible with deployment. Transfering files will do nothing

Comment: I think I remember Qt needs some other stuff to work, e.g. platforms/qwindows.dll. Procmon would be able to help if there's any other missing files.

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://github.com/brechtsanders/pedeps/releases

It contains a tool `copypedeps` which with the `-r` parameter recursively copies all of the dependancies along with the executable.

Also, you should probably copy the Qt's `plugins` folder (the entire folder itself, not its contents) into the folder where your .exe and .dll files are.